# Functionally define separation "goodness" in high D space

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning

I have binary classified data that exists in high dimensional space, but I have a large amount of options for which exact subspace I use to represent the data. How do I calculate how well binary data clusters in a given high dimensional space?

Here is an example of one particular high dimensional representation reduced to 2D with t-sne (for visualization purposes, the data persists in high D space)

[image: example projection of high D data]

I would like a functional way to say "this space was `x` good at seperating `True` and `False` data", so that this spacial representation of the data can be compared to some other spacial representation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't implemented it yet, but I think this will work:

- use k-means clustering to define clusters of data
- calculate `abs(0.5 - numTrue/(numTrue+numFalse))*2` to get how good a particular cluster is at seperating `True` and `Flase` data
- normalize all "goodnesses" for each cluster based on number of points
- sum all normalized "goodnesses", which would be how good a space is